# Execute C# code inside JavaScript function when it's called

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to execute a piece of C# code whenever I run a JavaScript function but it doesn't seem to behave the way I want it to here is an example:
Let's say that I have a variable `property int Counter {get; set; }` in the Model that I want to increment every time I run a JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MyFunction(){

    //Do some stuff
    @{Model.Counter++;}

}

</script>
```

What is really happening is that when the page loads `@{Model.Counter++;}` is getting executed regardless of not being called from the function.
And whenever I run the function again its ignoring it completely.
Meaning this piece of code `@{Model.Counter++;}` is getting executed once when the page loads and never again.
How do I fix that and make it execute every time I run the function?

Comment: JavaScript = Client, C# = Server

Comment: Razor is not some way to mingle server-side C# with client-side javascript. Instead it uses C# server side to generate html(+js) that will be sent to the browser. If you inspect your page in the browser, you will not see any C# (there will be a MyFunction, but it will be empty)

Comment: If you are not too far into your project you could come much closer to what you are trying to do with Blazor, which does run c# (sort of...) in the browser. The default template even comes with a Counter example.

Comment: Ok I think I got, you are right there is no C# code in the client side.
I am still new to ASP.NET, sorry for the obvious mistake and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am doing a project for my university and my Dr. want us to stick with C#, Javascript, CSS, HTML. :(
But maybe I will take a look at it for future purposes, Thanks.

Comment: Blazor is c#, javascript, css and html. I say "sort of" because it is ultimately [compiled to webassembly if you use the client-side hosting model but it is all c# if you use server-side.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You need not be concerned of the low-level details. You just write c#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible (maybe with Blazor? - but that is WebAssembly).
Instead you can assign a new javascript variable to your model property.
E.g.:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function MyFunction(){

    //Do some stuff
    let counter = @{Model.Counter};
    counter++;

    // Do some stuff with counter

}
// When you are done, post the counter back if needed on server side

</script>
```

Comment: My bad, obviously you need to increment the javascript variable. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveX control to execute Compiled program. but you should know that your html code only will work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a hidden field for model.counter somewhere inside  a view form

```
<input type="hidden" id="modelCounter" asp-for="Counter" value="@Model.Counter" />
```

after this you can change Counter using javascript

```
function MyFunction(){

    //Do some stuff

var counter=$("#modelCounter").val();
counter++;
   $("#modelCounter").val(counter);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
     @{
   var a=Model.Counter;
     }
```

do this outside the script

and inside the function or script
do

```
@a++;
```

or

```
 var c = @a;
    c++;
```

hope it works